# How to open file in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, file, fopen, readfile

I made sure that file exists at the location of the code.

```
text = fopen(string.txt,'r')
```

Errors:

```
>> Phy_rate_box_plot
Undefined variable "string" or class "string.txt".

Error in Phy_rate_box_plot (line 4)
text = fopen(string.txt,'r')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [fopen documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#inputarg_filename), you'll see that `filename` is supposed to be a string or a character array. To make string.txt a string, just enclose it in single quotes

```
text = fopen('string.txt','r')
```